# How can I add a kurtosis term in this Gaussian bell-curve formula?

Tags: math, numpy, gaussian, bell-curve

I am working with a formula to generate a curve in Python. I am tuning its parameters so that I can eyeball its matching over an underlying curve (already plotted).

What I need is to adjust its Kurtosis, which currently is not a parameter of the formula:

```
def gaussian(x, peak_x, peak_y, sigma):
    return numpy.exp(-numpy.power(x - peak_x, 2.) / (2 * numpy.power(sigma, 2.))) * peak_y
```

I would need to expand the function to this signature:

```
def gaussian(x, peak_x, peak_y, sigma, KURTOSIS)
```

But I don't know where and how to change the formula.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you mean by *add a Kurtosis term in the Gauassian Bell curve*.

The Gaussian Bell curve (also called the [Normal Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)) has a zero Kurtosis. Once you specify the mean and the variance, the graph is uniquely defined.

Assuming that you want to fit a Gaussian-like distribution to your data, I would suggest using one of the Pearson distributions. Specifically, [Pearson type VII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_distribution#The_Pearson_type_VII_distribution). These distributions will give you the liberty to define the mean, variance, skewness and Kurtosis so you get a perfect fit. However, if I understand your requirement correctly, you won't even need that level of flexibility. The [student's t-distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) should suffice.

You can find the equation on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Definition) and tune the Kurtosis by tuning the `v` parameter.

Comment: that's what I wanted, gonna take a look, thanks for now!